# What are the required .aar files for aarddict?

Tags: dictionary

I checked their wikipedia english dump which is about 14GB and opening it with utorrent I saw there are 4 or 5 seperate files. Do I have to download them all to aarddict to be functional or can I download just the 2GB file alone? (or one from the bunch?)

Comment: Have you considered asking the dev (or the app's community)? They are the best address for this. You could e.g. start checking [their issues](https://github.com/aarddict/android/issues) (could well be someone else already asked), and open your own request if you cannot find anything matching (consider checking the [closed issues](https://github.com/aarddict/android/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed) as well).

Answer (score 0):

Got it! fired up pc and checked the file and saw they all are chunks of a large file. so most popular wiki articles will be my bet.